# Does an AssetFileDescriptor in Android have to be closed

Tags: java, android

The `AssetFileDescriptor` in Android's API does have a [close method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#close%28%29). However, the documentation states that it is just a convenience method.

Does an `AssetFileDescriptor` object always have to be closed after its usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to call it.  I recommend using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct for convenience.  If you don't want the convenience, then you could call `getParcelFileDescriptor().close()` ;).